# What does for i in range(0, size): C[A[i]] += 1 mean in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I am new to programming and algorithms and was wondering what:

```
for i in range(0, size): C[A[i]] += 1
```

means. I know what range does though im not sure what C[A[i]] does/means.

This is the full code if necessary.

```
size = len(A)
B = [0] * size
C = [0] * (size+1)


for i in range(0, size): C[A[i]] += 1


for i in range(1, (size+1)): C[i] += C[i - 1]


i = size - 1 
while i >= 0:


B[C[A[i]] - 1] = A[i] C[A[i]] -= 1
i -= 1


for i in range(0, size): A[i] = B[i]


return A
A = [4, 2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 1]
```

Comment: It means nearly the same as "C[i] += 1" except that instead i the value of A[i] is used.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. you can visualize the execution at http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Comment: If you try running the code, printing the values of A, C and i at each step of the `for` loop, you may find all will become clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why indentation is so important in python.

This line:

```
for i in range(0, size): C[A[i]] += 1
```

Should be written:

```
for i in range(0, size):
    C[A[i]] += 1
```

Also unless there’s a specific meaning behind using just one letter variable names *(usually typical only in math equations and meaningless/throw-away variables)* I’d use better/more descriptive variable names.

A [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) is essentially a counter in iterator form. It counts from `start` to `stop` *(not including `stop`)* counting by increments of `step` (*defaults to `1`*). Being an iterator it’s memory usage is better than a list as the data is calculated on the fly vs holding integers in a list.

So for the first iteration `i` is 0; thus the command:

```
C[A[i]] += 1
```

Evaluates to:

```
C[A[0]] += 1
```

Then let’s say that `A[0]` is `5` so then it evaluates:

```
C[5] += 1
```

The `+=` is an inplace operator called [`__iadd__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=iadd#object.__iadd__). It adds and stores the result in that originating value. So it adds `1` to the value currently in `C[5]` and stores that value there.

Then the next iteration in the for loop it does the same although `i` is now `1` and so on until the range is exhausted or an Exception is raised.